# How to design a layout similar to twitter's reply to a tweet android

Tags: android-layout

On my app I when a user clicks on an item on the listview  on the postmessageActivtiy it takes them to  commentActivity , so I have been  trying to design a layout that is similar to twitter ‘s reply to a tweet activity .On the comment side I have  textviews that displays the postmessage and  the user name of the user who posted it , below that I have a listView that is used to display the comments , below the listview I have a textEdit and a Postbutton aligned to the right of the text edit. The problem I am facing is that the layout doesn’t look right   ,the  listviews that displays the message and the username  remain still on the same position whle  the listview below scrolls up and down.How do I make the whole thing scroll up and down together?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.machimanapc.howzit.CommentActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_left_white"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reply"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername_view_Respond"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="6pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/stuff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtUsername_view_Respond"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="end">
        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/txtContent_view_Respond"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="6pt"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_up"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_down"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stuff">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTimestamp_Reply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="@color/Timestamp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/feed_item_timestamp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/posts_list_view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/textColorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEdit_Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_reply"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtCharacter_count"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txtCharacter_count"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnPost"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/prompt_post"
        android:background="@drawable/newrounded"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCharacter_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPost"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnPost"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/character_count_placeholder"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: uuum, can't you, like style your question a bit? This is completely incomprehensible code / xml

Comment: I will try. Find it difficult to do that using the phone that I am using.